# DS3232 over DS3231?

Tags: pic, rtc, sram

I am working on PIC controller and testing different RTC modules. Recently I came across **DS3232** which is said to be an upgrade to DS3231. It says that DS3232 has an additional **236 bytes of SRAM**. I have worked with DS3231 module before and had found trouble in timekeeping when I plugged and unplugged the battery-backed module from my controller to test its functionally at the time of connection loss/ power down.
What I want to ask is that can this problem be solved by using the SRAM in DS3232. If yes then how can it be done?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in DS3231? DS3231 has reset pin which you could trigger by plugging your module.

Comment: I believe it should not be because of the Reset pin as I've also tested it by just shutting the Power(Vcc) pin and still it misses the time sometimes. Do you think that could be the reason why it resets?

Comment: Hard to say. You did not show any schematic at all. Add schematic of your module and schematic of your circuit you are attaching to.